# Prove that if $A\subset B$ then $P(A)\subset P(B)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A$ and $B$ being sets and $P(A)$ being the power set of $A$:
Prove that if $A\subset B$ then $P(A)\subset P(B)$.
It seems oblivious but I'm not sure how to write the proof properly.

Comment: Take an element in the power set, then this is a subset of A by definition, right? Then what follows from this?

Comment: Okey, every element of P(A) its a subset of A so its a subset B so its an element of P(B) therefore P(A)⊂P(B), thank you Pasternak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose (fill in details and watch carefully at the symbols)

$$X\in P(A)\implies X\subset A\subset B\implies X\subset B\implies X\in P(B)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $C\subset A$. Then since $A\subset B,$ we have $C\subset B$.